# How to separate columns in ps -ef command

Tags: linux, bash, command

I have the command:

```
ps -ef | grep kde | tr -s ' ' '@'
```

I`m getting output like this :

```
user2131@1626@1584@0@15:50@?@00:00:00@/bin/sh@/usr/bin/startkdeere
```

how can I get @ symbol only for column separation using linux or smth else like awk ?

Comment: Can you provide desired output example?

Answer (score 1):

Nasty but it works. Tweak the number 8 to suit the number of columns your variant of ps outputs.

```sh
ps -ef | awk -v OFS="" '{ for(i=1; i < 8; i++) printf("%s@",$i); for(i=8; i <= NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("\n")}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pgrep` to get your PIDs instead of using `ps`. `pgrep` will eliminate the *grep* issue where one of the processes you discover is the `grep` doing your filtering.

You can also specify the output of the `ps` command itself using the `-o` or `-O` option. You can do this to get the fields you want, and eliminate the header.

You can also use the read command to *parse* your output. The only field you have with possible blank space is the last one -- the command and arguments.

```
ps -o uid= -o gid= -o tty= -o args= -p $(pgrep kde) | while read uid gid tty cmd
do
    echo "UID = $uid   PID = $pid   TTY = $tty"
    echo "Command = $cmd"
done
```

The `while` will split on whitespace except for the `$cmd` which will include all the leftover fields (i.e. the entire command with arguments).

The `ps` command differs from platform to platform, so read the manpage on `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean process your output with '@' as a column/field separator, in awk you can use -F:

```
echo "user2131@1626@1584@0@15:50@?@00:00:00@/bin/sh@/usr/bin/startkdeere" | awk -F'@' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1;print $0}'
```

Output:

```
user2131        1626    1584    0       15:50   ?       00:00:00        /bin/sh /usr/bin/startkdeere
```

Comment: Isn't that pretty much what we had before `tr -s ' ' '@'`?

Comment: no, I need such output: user2131@1626@1584@... only for columns , not for spaces

Comment: In the example above are you saying that you want a '@' symbol between all fields but you want to keep the space in the following string "/bin/sh /usr/bin/startkdeere"?

Comment: @user2734570 Do you plan to save your output on a file and process it later, but prefer storing it with @ for field separator?

Comment: No, it should be only as output in terminal